# How to resolve java.lang.LinkageError org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.SMIMESignedGenerator.generate(Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart;)

Tags: java, jboss, bouncycastle, jboss-eap-6

I am using Bouncycastle (bcmail, bcprov, bcpkix) 1.57 in combination with Jboss EAP 6.4 (jboss-AS 7.5) and Java 1.8.

I get a Linkage error with the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: 
loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.SMIMESignedGenerator.generate(Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart;)Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart;"

the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, de/deutschepost/paket/mkp/transformation/SMIMEPreparator, 
and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMESignedGenerator, 
have different Class objects for the type javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart used in the signature
```

As far as my understanding goes there must be a duplicate or a conflict in  library versions somewhere in the hierarchy, but unfortunately I can't find any.

Here is the list of all the dependencies that are present in the classpath at runtime:

```
activation-1.1.jar
activemq-broker-5.11.0.jar
activemq-client-5.11.0.jar
activemq-jms-pool-5.11.0.jar
activemq-openwire-legacy-5.11.0.jar
activemq-pool-5.11.0.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aqapi-11.2.0.3-1.jar
asm-5.0.4.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.1.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar
c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar
camel-core-2.18.4.jar
camel-cxf-2.18.4.jar
camel-cxf-transport-2.18.4.jar
camel-ftp-2.18.4.jar
camel-http-2.18.4.jar
camel-http-common-2.18.4.jar
camel-jaxb-2.18.4.jar
camel-jetty-2.18.4.jar
camel-jetty9-2.18.4.jar
camel-jetty-common-2.18.4.jar
camel-jms-2.18.4.jar
camel-mail-2.18.4.jar
camel-mail-patch-2.10-senacor-3-SNAPSHOT.jar
camel-ognl-2.18.4.jar
camel-quartz2-2.18.4.jar
camel-spring-2.18.4.jar
cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
classmate-1.3.0.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-net-3.3.jar
commons-pool-1.5.6.jar
core-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
cryptacular-1.0.jar
cxf-core-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.11.jar
cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth-3.1.11.jar
cxf-rt-security-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-security-saml-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.12.jar
cxf-rt-ws-security-3.1.12.jar
dms-11.2.0.3-1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dsn-1.5.5.jar
ehcache-2.10.3.jar
ehcache-core-2.5.7.jar
geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.jar
gson-2.7.jar
guava-18.0.jar
h2-1.3.173.jar
hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hawtbuf-1.11.jar
hibernate-c3p0-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-5.2.10.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
httpmime-4.5.3.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
jasypt-1.9.2.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
java-support-7.1.1.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.mail-1.5.5.jar
javax.mail-api-1.5.5.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.6.3.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jettison-1.3.7.jar
jetty-client-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-continuation-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-http-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-io-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-jmx-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-security-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-server-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-servlet-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-servlets-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jetty-util-9.2.21.v20170120.jar
jms-1.1.jar
joda-time-2.3.jar
jsch-0.1.54.jar
jsmpp-2.1.0.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
jsr250-api-1.0.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jutf7-1.0.0.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar
neethi-3.0.3.jar
netty-all-4.0.26.Final.jar
oauth-20100527.jar
oauth-provider-20100527.jar
ognl-3.1.10.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar
opensaml-core-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-profile-api-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-saml-api-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-saml-impl-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-security-api-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-security-impl-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-soap-api-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-xacml-api-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-xacml-impl-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-xacml-saml-api-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-xacml-saml-impl-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-xmlsec-api-3.1.1.jar
opensaml-xmlsec-impl-3.1.1.jar
optivo-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
pushy-0.4.3.jar
quartz-2.2.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jdbc-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-oracle-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
ucp-11.2.0.4.0.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
velocity-1.6.2.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
wss4j-bindings-2.1.10.jar
wss4j-policy-2.1.10.jar
wss4j-ws-security-common-2.1.10.jar
wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.1.10.jar
wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax-2.1.10.jar
wss4j-ws-security-stax-2.1.10.jar
xbean-spring-3.5.jar
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlschema-core-2.2.2.jar
xmlsec-2.0.8.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.4.5.jar
xstream-hibernate-1.4.5.jar
```

Apart from these I have an explicit dependency to Bouncycastle module (I added the module myself in jboss modules). The configuration file module.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.bouncycastle">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="bcmail-jdk15on-1.57.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="bcprov-jdk15on-1.57.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
        <module name="javax.activation.api" />
        <module name="javax.mail.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I would be glad if anyone can help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: `bcmail, bcprov, bcpk'x` what version of java do they use,is there any java version other then 1.8 shipped explicitly here?Please check if it is compatible.Are you using `activation.jar or javax.mail.api` other then the one provide by EAp

Comment: I can see that on JBoss EAP version javax.mail.api-1.4.5 is present,please check at your end,are there any CP's applied or is this EAP 6.4?

Comment: I happened to have resolved the issue and you are right about problem being multiple javax-mail dependencies. If you can post it as answer, I can mark it as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to presence of `multiple javax-mail versions`in the project classpath.Removing all the different versions for this dependency and keeping just one would resolve the issue.By default you could try using javax.mail.api-1.4.5 which is shipped with EAP 6.4